# Не появляется картинка в приложении Ruby on Rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

Хочу на странице вывести картинку:

```
<%= link_to image_tag("rails.png", alt: "Rails logo"), 'http://rubyonrails.org/' %>
```

Картинка находится по адресу app/assets/images/rails.png
В исходном коде страницы картинка выводится так:

```
<img alt="Rails logo" src="/images/rails.png">
```

Как это можно исправить?
Где находится файл конфига, чтобы задать правильно prefix?

Comment: Ну вообще всё написано правильно. Может какая-то проблема с доступом к самой картинке?

Comment: @check1st путь неправильный ему выдает. По дефолту Rails все раздает по пути `/assets/`, а далее у имена файла приписывается хэш.

Comment: там еще есть второй вопрос, Где находится файл конфига, чтобы задать правильно prefix? Спасибо за ответы.